# Angular one Module with multiple controller not working

Tags: angularjs

Am new to angular js, is it possible to create multiple controller in single module?

```html
   

<body ng-app="birth" >
 <div ng-controller="learnerToSurvive" ng-show="$learn">
  <p>xxx</p>
  <button ng-click="start">Let's Begin</button>
 </div>
 <div ng-controller="startToSurvive" ng-show="$begin">
  <button ng-model="$CPU"> VS CPU </button>
  <button ng-model="$multiplayer"> Multiplayer</button>
  <div ng-show="$options">
   <label for="two">Two</label><input type="radio" id="two" ng-model="$players" name="multi" text="two"/>
   <label for="three">Three</label><input type="radio" id="three" ng-model="$players" name="multi" text="three"/>
   <label for="four">Four</label><input type="radio" id="four" ng-model="$players" name="multi" text="four"/>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div ng-controller="surviveBegins" ng-show="$play">
  <canvas id="survival" style="height: 300px, widht:500px">
 </div>
 <div ng-controller="death" ng-show="$over">
 </div>

</body>
```

Comment: whats not working? show the js code defining your controller?

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty simple to achieve with `$rootScope` although this is not recommended.

I have provided a jsfiddle for my example:
http://jsfiddle.net/dn4e4j01/1/

In my opinion, ui-router would be a much better approach:

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it is.
If those controllers are properly defined in your Javascript files, there should be no problem.
Though, based on your example, maybe you need something like [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) to go from one state to another.

Comment: This doesnt answer the question